# (Basic) How to connect the ground in this schematic to a breadboard?

Tags: ground, basic

How do I connect the ground in the circuit? I know how to connect DC source but I'm confused on how to connect the ground. I have adept knowledge about the concept of ground, I just want to know how to connect the ground (0 V) in this schematic to a breadboard. I'm just playing with the basics in Falstad but I got confused about this.

[image]

Comment: the "ground" here is just reference .. not the real earth ground .. usually the ground is the negative terminal of the battery .. so the other pin of the 800ohm resistor

Comment: Ok I got it thanks for a quick reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to connect that part of the circuit to any ground.
The ground of that particular circuit in that particular example is there only as a reference point to show how other potentials (voltages) relate to it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. Very much appreciated..

Comment: Hi, sorry for disturbing you, is the ground in this common base circuit schematic can also be removed when connecting to a breadboard? 
https://i.imgur.com/vifsZQi.jpg
So if I understand correctly on what you have explained, these grounds in schematics is just a reference or representation. These grounds can be removed when applying to a breadboard?

Comment: Normally, circuits explaining theory of operation use ground as reference point for your understanding, but in practical circuits the ground is used as a common 0V reference for signals and voltages, and it can be critical to proper operation. It all depends on the actual circuit.